# how to Horizontal box UIButtons?

Tags: xcode, swift

I am required to make a view where number of buttons to be displayed will depend upon the argument to init. how can i make it possible horizontal box  UIButtons?

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    var bs = 0;
   for index in 1...20
   {
        bs+=50;var x = CGFloat(bs)
        let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        button.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
        button.frame = CGRectMake(x, 50, 40, 40) // X, Y, width, height
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        button.setTitle("12", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button);
        }
       }
```

[image: i want to like this]

i want to like this

Comment: no. but i dont want to use UICollectionView in my project.Can u give me otter options please ?

Comment: If you not want to use collection view than only option is to add this in Scrollview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably look at [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/)

If you don't want to use a UICollectionView, I put up for you this small sample, on which you can try to build on, whether using a UIView or UIScrollView:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

let buttonHeight = 40
let buttonWidth = 40
let marginInterCell = 10
let marginInterRow = 20

let numberOfButtonsInRow = 300/(buttonWidth + marginInterCell)
let totalNumberOfButtons = 20

for index in 0..totalNumberOfButtons {
    let button  = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    button.titleLabel?.text = "\(index)"
    let x = (index % numberOfButtonsInRow) * (buttonWidth + marginInterCell) + marginInterCell/2
    let y = (buttonHeight + marginInterRow) * (index / numberOfButtonsInRow) + marginInterRow/2
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    button.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), size: CGSize(width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight))
    view.addSubview(button)
}
```

Comment: i know how can i use UICollectionView but in my project i must use view.addSubview .So Can You help me for view.addSubview ?